# PHP Regex match for file paths

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex match that can match to file paths. Basically I am trying to match something which has "/" in the string and ends with "."something.

Ex: test/helpers/home/file_name.php

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use sth. like (see [**the demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/R7Q7jS/1))

```
(?=[^/]*/).+\.php
```

Or `glob()`, [**see the documentation on php.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).